# SQL Server select nth to nth in result set in multisearch

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

As the following SQL, it will select the 100 to 110th result matching the search condition. But I think the SQL is ugly (using twice condition `where [name] like '%%'`) and there should be some brief statement to reach the same goal.

```
SELECT top 10 [name], [field1], [field2]
FROM [FrontPageInformation] 
WHERE [name] LIKE '%%' AND [name] NOT IN
      (SELECT TOP 100 [name] 
       FROM [EngineeringMedicine].[dbo].[FrontPageInformation] 
       WHERE [name] LIKE '%%')
```

Could anyone help?

Great thanks,

Wa

Comment: `TOP` must be accompanied by `ORDER BY` to get predictable results.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` syntax to get the row number

eg:

```
select [name],[field1],[field2] 
from
(
  SELECT [name],[field1],[field2], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY something) as RN
  FROM [FrontPageInformation]
  WHERE [name] like '%something%'
) v
WHERE RN between 101 and 110
```